# Comparing event and adding new field in Riemann

Tags: clojure, riemann

I am facing one scenario. Let assume I have 3 events A, B and C which I am passing to Riemann.

Event A have following fields
   :ExamNo 3890
   :ExamResult Pass
   :Rank 8
Event B have following fields
   :ExamNo 3890
   :ExamResult Pass
   :Rank 5
Event C have following fields
   :ExamNo 3890
   :ExamResult Fail
   :Rank 0

I need to compare the events based on ExamNo and whenver there is a change in ExamResult I need to add a new fields to event {:Eligible, :Grade}. I wrote the code to compare the events but the new field was not getting added to the event.

```
(let [examindex (default :ttl 300 (update-index (index)))]
  (streams
    prn
    examindex))

(streams
  (where (service "Result")
    (smap
          (fn [events]
        (by[:ExamNo]
        (changed :ExamResult))
        (event
            {    :Eligible :Eligible-Status
                 :Grade     :GradeValue
            }
         )))))
```

Since I am newbie to Riemann . I couldn't figure out the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never used Riemann, but since you want to modify existing events, you  should probably use [`with`](http://riemann.io/api/riemann.streams.html#var-with), as [explained here](http://riemann.io/howto.html#filter-events), instead of `event`. By the way, just to be clear, events are immutables, so you are in fact creating new values based on older ones.

You should try to indent your code: notice that the `(event ...)` form is not enclosed under `(changed ...)`, althought it probably should.

#### Tests

I use only this `streams` declaration, in the configuration file:

```
(streams
 (where (service "Result")
    (by :ExamNo
      (changed :ExamResult
        (with {:Eligible :Eligible-Status
               :Grade    :GradeValue  }
          prn)))))))
```

I removed `smap` and added a `prn` statement.
In order to test this, I connected to an `nREPL` client and fired events from there. First, let's define a TCP client.

```
(def tcp-client (riemann.client/tcp-client))
```

Then, send a first event, with no `:ExamResult` value:

```
(riemann.client/send-event tcp-client
  (riemann.common/event {:service "Result" :ExamNo "4"}))
```

Nothing is printed by the server. Then, I send a new event for the same `ExamNo` with a result:

```
(riemann.client/send-event tcp-client
  (riemann.common/event {:service "Result" :ExamNo "4" :ExamResult "result"}))
```

Since the result changed for exam number "4" since last event, we build a new event. The running Riemann server outputs the following in its standard output:

```
#riemann.codec.Event{:host "localhost", :service "Result", :state nil, 
:description nil, :metric nil, :tags nil, :time 1437035833,
:ttl nil, :Grade :GradeValue, :Eligible :Eligible-Status, 
:ExamNo "4", :ExamResult "x"}
```

#### Reinject

If, instead of `prn`, I use `reinject`, and if I restore the previously omitted lines:

```
(let [examindex (default :ttl 300 (update-index (index)))]
  (streams
    prn
    examindex))
```

... then all events are shown, in particular the new events being reinjected. This behaviour might be the one you expected to have in the first place.

Comment: I tried your logic also using (with: but no luck those fields are not getting added to my event if the (changed :ExamResult condition was satisfied.

Comment: @Magnoski Shouldn't there be a `prn` function, for example as a child of `smap`, to see what events are printed? I would like to know what is your methodology for testing/debugging in order to reproduce tests.

Comment: (let [examindex (default :ttl 300 (update-index (index)))]
  (streams
    prn
    examindex)) I am alreading printing the index know. will not that work

Comment: @Mangoski From what I understand, new events won't be visible unless you explicitely [reinject](http://riemann.io/api/riemann.config.html#var-reinject) them. Hope it helps.

Comment: Its working awesome but when I am trying to add the field :Eligible-Status and :Gradevalue dynamically but the value of the field was not passing instead of that I am getting the field name as it is in my event. How can I add the values dynamically